# Access a dictionary value by variable

Tags: python, dictionary

here are two dictionaries

```
all_info = {'brazil':{'prduct_prices':{"iphone":100, "ipod":65},
                      'product_stock':{"iphone":100, "ipod":100},
                      'validations' :{"passport":"^B[0-9]{3}[A-Z]{2}[A-Z|0-9]{7}$"}},
            'argentina':{'prduct_prices':{"iphone":100, "ipod":65},
                      'product_stock':{"iphone":100, "ipod":100},
                      'validations' :{"passport":"^A[A-Z]{2}[A-Z|0-9]{9}$"}}}

order = order = {'country': 'brazil', 'ipod': '30'}
```

This is the Line of Code that is causing problem

```
country = self.order['country']
if re.match(all_info[[country]['validations']['passport']],self.order[key]):
                    print 'Here i came'
```

***now thing is IN PHP if i would have enclosed country in {}, like [{country}] it would have worked.*** but in python i can't seem to get the same workflow by any means, it is very clear that what i am trying to to.. Can anyone suggest how to get [key] filled with a dynamic value

error which i am getting is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
all_info[country]['validations']['passport']
```

The original code is `all_info[expr]` where expr is `[country]['validations']['passport']` and is effectively doing this:

```
lst = [country]       # create list
lst['validations']    # error here; not using an integer indice for a list
```

Answer (score 0):

What is happening right now is that Python is interpreting `country` as a list and trying to retrieve indices 'validations' and 'passport' from it (which cannot happen as they are strings and not integers). Change it to:

`all_info[country]['validations']['passport']`

Comment: yup, thats was some serious syntax mistake, i came to realise as soon as i saw first answer